# Add iOS Swift dependency to a pre existing flutter plugin

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-plugin

So this is my situation.

I have a plugin that was constructed by a guy for android. Now I am supposed to construct the iOS for it.

I locally prepared a new flutter plugin with swift dependency and added the podspec and it worked.

Now when I am looking into the plugin where I have to merge the code, I am facing 2 obstacles

1. My local flutter plugin has Swift artifacts. Which means that with the generic .h and .m file, there is a swift file. In the .m file, the Swift file is incorporated via the following code

   *#import "ios_box_flutter/ios_box_flutter-Swift.h>"*

which I think means that this is the Bridging Header file. But I cannot find the physical existence of this file at all.

and then in the implementation part it goes like this

```
@implementation IosBoxFlutterPlugin
+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar>*)registrar {
  [SwiftIosBoxFlutterPlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar];
}

@end
```

None of this is present in the android plugin that has been already created.

2. The plugin requires a swift pod to be installed. Now if I try to do that with the pre-existing android plugin ( which only has .h and .m files only ) If I need to use the swift pod, then I think we need a bridging header for that. How can I prepare the bridging header for this swift pod.